# Intuition behind generic point of a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, intuition

I've been reading a little about algebraic geometry and how there seems to have existed this notion of "generic point" on a variety which wasn't carefully defined at first. But often times, intuitively one would try to prove a statement at a generic point to get a statement about the overall variety.

I suppose what I'm asking is: how can I understand the notion of a generic point in the most concrete sense? I know that $X = Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ has $(0)$ as a generic point because it's Zariski closure is all of $X$, but what does that say geometrically?

Suppose I take $V = V(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $Spec(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1))$. Then $(0)$ is a generic point in the latter (because only maximal ideals correspond to the actual points of $V$, yes?). So how can I visualize this generic point when all I'm thinking about in my mind is the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

As an addendum, what sort of properties did geometers in the early 1900s observe a variety would possess if they could show its "generic point" had this property? (Just as a reference to see where this idea is even coming from, because it feels very unintuitive to me at the moment.) Is there some property about all the other rational primes we can deduce by proving something about $(0) \in Spec(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: A generic point in the technical sense is precisely a point whose closure is the whole space. You can think of it as saying that any property that holds on closed subspaces that holds at the generic point must hold everywhere. As for $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R} [x, y] / (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$, you should _not_ be visualising it as a circle at all. (Consider, for instance, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R} [x, y] / (x^2 + y^2 + 1)$, which has no real-valued points but is nonetheless non-trivial.)

Comment: Good question, but hard to answer: it's hard to make generic points correspond to anything one can really visualise. (The human mind is a Hausdorff space.) You could try looking in Hartshorne Ch. II where he has a picture of generic points in $\mathbf A^2$, or even better, Google "mumford treasure map". As for the addendum, this has definitely been discussed on MathOverflow.

Comment: Zhen Lin: I understand the danger of not using an algebraically closed field, but I just wanted a concrete geometric example to demonstrate my current level of understanding.

Comment: Relapsarian: Do you have a source for the topic on MathOverflow regarding some properties to be proven about $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ by proving something about $(0)$?